# Não estou conseguindo usar as fontes do Google no CSS e os códigos estão certos, aparentemente

Tags: css

Copiei e colei os dois códigos que o Google disponibiliza, mas não sei o problema.

Obs: O problema é com a tag `<h2>`

Então agradeço se reponderem, pois como vi em vários videos, o procedimento é pegar os dois códigos, um para o style e outro pra tag, mas no meu não está funcionando.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não seria problema de cache? Coloque um `?1` após o `.css`, assim: `estilo.css?1`

Comment: Cara não coloque imagens com o código, Edite sua pergunta e cole o código completo do que já tem ai para a gente pode ajudar.

Comment: cara, substitua as imagens pelo código. Pois, dificilmente encontrará ajuda para o seu problema, devido ao fato de que a resolução está péssima.

Answer (score 0):

Tente fechar a tag **h2**, você abriu mas não fechou. Está assim `<h2>Lorem ipsum is...<h2>`
O corrento seria assim `<h2>Lorem ipsum is...</h2>`